# Data transfering from iPhone to iWatch with Watch connectivity framework

Tags: ios, watchkit, data-transfer, watchconnectivity

I want to ask a question about watch connectivity.

1) Is it possible to read data from iPhone when the iWatch app opened. I not want to wait to open iPhone app for transfering data to iWatch.

2) Is it possible to create login screen(to get user input from text fields) on iWatch

3) iWatch has device token and vendor id? How to get these infos from iWatch?

4) Is it possible to read iPhone app's database(like sql lite db on iPhone app) from iWatch application

5) How to transfer dictionary from iPhone app to iWatch app. Share any example plz.

Comment: Please limit your post to a single question, and make sure what you are asking is not off-topic. See [ask] for details. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) Is it possible to read data from iPhone when the iWatch app opened. I not want to wait to open iPhone app for transferring data to iWatch.**

YES, Using any of background methods (`transferUserInfo:`, `transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo:`, `transferFile:`,`updateApplicationContext:infoToSend` ) you can awake iPhone app and get things done. vice versa is not possible Watch app has to be Opened.

**2) Is it possible to create login screen(to get user input from text fields) on iWatch**

NO, Text fields are not available in WatchOS2.

**3) iWatch has device token and vendor id? How to get these info from iWatch?**

With watchOS 1, the vendor ID and the advertising ID were actually on the iPhone as the WatchKit extension itself ran on the iPhone.

With watchOS 2, you will need to sync the vendor ID and advertising ID from the iPhone to the Watch and use it there.
And you will need to maintain the vendor ID and advertising ID up-to-date.

**4) Is it possible to read iPhone app's database(like sql lite db on iPhone app) from iWatch application**

It was possible in WatchKit but with the introduction of WatchConnectivity Framework App group based common container has been restricted.I am sure for UserDefualts but not have yet tested for Files.

**5) How to transfer dictionary from iPhone app to iWatch app. Share any example plz.**

There are Two ways to perform these things:

**Using TransferUserInfo**

With this method, Watch will receive dictionary everytime, that means if Watch is inactive and iphone sends 3 Dictionary during that time period, Whenever watch will activate, it will receive all the 3 dictionary by multiple calls of delegate methods - `- (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveUserInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)userInfo` on watch side.

```
-(void)sendDictionaryToWatch:(NSDictionary*)infoToSend{
        if([WCSession isSupported]){
            WCSession *aDefaultSession           = [WCSession defaultSession];
            aDefaultSession.delegate  = self;
            if([aDefaultSession isPaired] && [aDefaultSession isWatchAppInstalled]){
                [aDefaultSession activateSession];
                [aDefaultSession transferUserInfo:infoToSend];
            }
        }
    }
```

**Using updateApplicationContext:error:**

In this case, Device will send the latest Context to Watch on activation. That means let say If you have sent three Info back to back then When Watch is Activated it will receive only latest one, not previous ones in delegate method - `-(void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveApplicationContext:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)applicationContext`.

```
-(void)sendDictionaryToWatch:(NSDictionary*)infoToSend{
    if([WCSession isSupported]){
        WCSession *aDefaultSession           = [WCSession defaultSession];
        aDefaultSession.delegate  = self;
        if([aDefaultSession isPaired] && [aDefaultSession isWatchAppInstalled]){
            [aDefaultSession activateSession];
            [aDefaultSession updateApplicationContext:infoToSend error:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answers. @Mrug  For my first question i used updateApplicationContext method and get dictionary on watch side but to do this i have to awake(open) iPhone app firstly. I want to do get data from iPhone app to iWatch without awake(open) iPhone app. Is it possible? For my third question what do you want to tell with "sync"? Can give an example code to get vendor id & device token on iWatch side?

Comment: @oaktuna : Nope. You will not need to Open iPhone. Your app will wake up in background only. In case of Watch as i said its mandatory to open app.

regarding sync, i mean your own logic to transfer Vendor ID from device to watch. you can use any of transfer method that i explained.

May i know downvote for what ?