# How to pass data from iPhone app to a Glance on Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch-glances

I need to send data from iPhone app to Apple Watch Glance periodically. How do I do this in Objective-C?

Answer (score -2):

To send or receive date from the iPhone, you have to use WCSession. Refer to Apple developer site. Also youtube user tutorial video is very helpful to you.

In my experience, I use a NSTimer object in order to trigger a call to an update method and pass data periodically. I think it is easy way. When the user taps a glance, the Apple Watch will launch app by calling the main interface controller.

Refer to this article http://www.chupamobile.com/blog/2015/05/27/apple-watch-glances-in-deep/ This article is very useful to you.

Comment: How do I send the data from the iPhone app and how should I receive the data in the Glance Interface Controller?

Comment: To send or receive  date from the iPhone, you have to use WCSession. Refer to Apple developer site. Also youtube user tutorial video is very helpful to you.

Comment: Check this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36617639/data-transfering-from-iphone-to-iwatch-with-watch-connectivity-framework/36646252#36646252